# c++ easy way to print out value in json formatted char*

Tags: c++, json

A really simple question but I did some research and most people suggest convert to Json class, but is there an easier way to do this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    const char *json = "{\"hello\": \"world\"}";
    cout<< json["hello"] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If I know the key is "hello", is there a way that I can simply print the value "world"? like json[key]?

Comment: C++ knows nothing about JSON -- It isn't JavaScript.  You need a library (recommended) or create your own code (not really recommended).

Comment: No, there is no easy way.

Comment: Casablanca/CppRest is your friend https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk

Comment: I use jsoncpp (open source library), but there are plenty of json parsers out there.